# How to get view in Java when using merge and include tags?

Tags: android, xml, merge, include

I have multiple include tags inside my activity's layout XML file. I created a reusable layout using "merge" since I don't want any redundancy of layouts.

I need to obtain each TextView in my layout. I know how to do it if I don't use merge, but is there any way to do this using merge, and if there isn't, is there any other way to reuse the XML and also avoid the redundancy?

Code:
layout_reusable.xml:

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My TextView"/>
</merge>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="*.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_reusable"
        android:id="@+id/number1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_reusable"
        android:id="@+id/number2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_reusable"
        android:id="@+id/number3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your posted code, there's no need for the `<merge>` tag. The merge tag is meant to be used when your included layout has **multiple** views without a root view. When you have only one view in your included layout, you can omit the merge tag.

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My TextView"/>
```

The other part of the problem is how the attributes on the include tag are applied to the included layout. Normally, these attributes would be applied to the included layout's root view, but (since you're using `<merge>`), there isn't a root view. So those ids will just be dropped on the floor (unless you remove the merge tag from the included layout).

If you don't want to change any of your layout files, then the only way to look up the views (since they'll all have the same id) will be `getChildAt()`.